# Determine if any model of the following language has a finite model elementarily equivalent to it

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

Let $L$ be a language with no equals, with one unary function symbol $g$ and one unary relation symbol $G$. Let $M_1$ be any infinite model of $L$.

Does there exist a finite model $M_2$ such that $M_1$ and $M_2$ are elementarily equivalent?

I think the answer is no, but I can't seem to find a counterexample. Is there a simple infinite model $M_1$ that interprets $L$ such that there are no elementarily equivalent finite models?

Comment: Shouldn't you state that $M_1$ is infinite? Also do you take equality to be a logical symbol (which is common practice)?

Comment: Yes, $M_1$ is infinite and crucially $L$ has no equals sign. That's why I think the statement is false. But I'm struggling with a counterexample

Comment: I forgot to mention $L$ has no equals sign

Comment: Is $G$ a unary relation symbol?.

Comment: Yes, its unary. Sorry I keep forgetting to mention details.

Comment: The answer certainly isn't a simple "no". If $G(x)$ is true for every $x$, then the theory of $M_1$ is just propositional logic - the  universe of $M_1$ plays no part in the truth of the formulas.

Answer (score 2):

Your intuition is right: while *some* infinite $\{G,g\}$-structures are equality-freely-elementarily-equivalent (EFE-equivalent) to some finite ones, not all of them are. Whipping up a counterexample requires two ideas: we can use the unary relation $G$ to distinguish objects on an "immediate" level, and we can use the unary function $g$ to "probe deeper."

---

First, let me start with recapping the trivial stuff. If we had equality in our language, we'd get a trivial negative answer: in the first-order-*with*-equality theory of an infinite structure we have sentences saying "There are at least $n$ distinct objects" for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, and so no finite structure is ever elementarily equivalent to an infinite one ... **if** equality were allowed.

In order to whip up an infinite structure not EFE-equivalent to any finite one, we need to find a way to work around this. Specifically, we need a way to somehow talk about inequality without using "$=$." So:

> What are some ways that a language consisting of a unary relation symbol $G$ and a unary function symbol $g$ can distinguish between two objects ... *without* using $=$?

Well, there's one obvious way which only involves one of our symbols: if $G$ holds of one thing but fails of another, those two things are distinct. Or to put it more usefully, the sentence

> $$(*)_2:\quad \exists x,y[G(x)\wedge\neg G(y)]$$

can only be true in a structure with at least two elements.

Since in fact we can whip up a model of that sentence, this shows that without using the function symbol $g$ we can at least count to $2$:

> There is a $\{G\}$-structure which is not EFE-equivalent to any one-element structure. Specifically, any such structure in which $G$ holds of some but not all elements of the domain will have this property.

That's ... not great though. And in fact you can show **(exercise)** that every $\{G\}$-structure *is* EFE-equivalent to a two-element structure. So somehow we need to get a lot of leverage out of that function symbol.

I'll pose the question as follows:

> What is a more complicated way we can distinguish between elements $x$ and $y$ using $G$ and $g$ (but not $=$ of course)?

Well, it's still the case that the only "verb" we have is $G$, so whatever formula we're thinking about has to break into pieces of the form "$G(...)$" and "$\neg G(...)$." But by using $g$ we can talk, not just about the "$G$-ness" of an element, but the "depth-$2$ $G$-ness," the "depth-$3$ $G$-ness," and so forth - and this gives rise to more incompatible possibilities.

Here, for example, is a way to imply that there are at least four elements using just $G$ and $g$:

> In order for the sentence $$(*)_4:\quad \exists x,y,z,w[G(x)\wedge G(y)\wedge\neg G(z)\wedge\neg G(w)$$ $$\wedge G(g(x))\wedge G(g(z))\wedge\neg G(g(y))\wedge\neg G(g(w))]$$ to be true in a structure, that structure must have at least four elements.

Do you see a way to generalize this to arbitrary $n\in\mathbb{N}$? Now consider a structure in which *all* of these sentences hold ...